# Akka Projection configuration for a JDBC database connection

Tags: scala, jdbc, akka, akka-projection

In Akka Projection’s documentation under [offsetting in a relational database with JDBC](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-projection/current/jdbc.html), there is no information about how and where the configuration for establishing a connection to the relational database used should be included. I mean configs such as the username, password, or the url.

In the documentation under [offset in a relational database with Slick](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-projection/current/slick.html), the following configuration is provided for the database connection, which is unclear whether it can be used for JDBC as well:

```
# add here your Slick db settings
  db {
    # url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test1"
    # driver = org.h2.Driver
    # connectionPool = disabled
    # keepAliveConnection = true
  }
```

How and where should I specify the JDBC connection parameters?

Answer (score 2):

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-projection/current/jdbc.html#defining-a-jdbcsession

The following line in the Scala code snippet is where you can specify connection parameters:

```scala
val c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1")
```

Comment: It seems like that connection is for establishing the JDBC session used for projecting the records to. It’s not for accessing the [schema](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-projection/current/jdbc.html#schema) used by the projection itself. Or should the schema of projection be placed on the same JDBC database the records get projected to?

Comment: I think according to "When using JdbcProjection.exactlyOnce, the JdbcSession that is passed to the handler will be used to save the offset behind the scenes. “ I need to put the schema on the same database.

Comment: Yes, you have to create the schema in the database, and then establish a connection to this database in `JdbcSession`.